# using ffmpeg and node to stream a fixed video

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, node-media-server

I am trying to use a node module to stream a video on a website. The modules name is `node-media-server`. I currently have set it up to work when streaming a live source from obs and it works fine. What I can't figure out is how to stream a fixed h.264 video. There npm documentation says to use FFMPEG but this got me confused what does this exactly mean. How do I use ffmpeg to publish the fixed video to the node media server? The how to is mentioned under the "Publishing live streams" section in their npm documentation. Can you please help me understand how ffmpeg will come in handy here? Thanks in advance.

**Their npm documentation:** https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-media-server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used fluent-ffmpeg to run the ffmpeg command from node js and it works.

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path')

const ffmpegPath = require('@ffmpeg-installer/ffmpeg').path;
const fluent = require('fluent-ffmpeg');
fluent.setFfmpegPath(ffmpegPath);

const executeFfmpeg = args => {
  let command = fluent().output(' '); // pass "Invalid output" validation
  command._outputs[0].isFile = false; // disable adding "-y" argument
  command._outputs[0].target = ""; // bypass "Unable to find a suitable output format for ' '"
  command._global.get = () => { // append custom arguments
    return typeof args === "string" ? args.split(' ') : args;
  };
  return command;
};

executeFfmpeg(`ffmpeg -re -i INPUT_FILE_NAME -c copy -f flv rtmp://localhost/live/STREAM_NAME`)
  .on('start', commandLine => console.log('start', commandLine))
  .on('codecData', codecData => console.log('codecData', codecData))
  .on('error', error => console.log('error', error))
  .on('stderr', stderr => console.log('stderr', stderr))
  .run();
```

Comment: What is actually STREAM_NAME is? Where is it binding to, and could we store some kind of formatted video to there without ffmpeg? Like manually converted mp4 to hls video.

Comment: @TheArKa STREAM_NAME is just a random name you specify to later identify the stream you want on client side. I don't fully understand your second question but yes you can convert mp4 to hls or other video formats with ffmpeg. There are a lot of posts about how to do it on SO.

Comment: I mean, let say that `localhost/live/STREAM_NAME.hls` is a valid url for HLS, then where is `STREAM_NAME.hls` file saved in the project with `node-media-server`? Some of the documentation code includes `mediaroot: './media',` in `http` but then how could it accessed from `/live/` url path? How the media assets structured in the project so it could be accessed. In a simple words, I thought I'm looking for a running example.

Comment: wait so what is your end goal? Is it streaming a video through rtmp which will then be accessing through an address or is it storing/recording a live stream?

Comment: Accessing, but it need the video to be stored first so I'm going to just "store it manually for testing" too.

Comment: ok so it's pretty easy. First store the video, then supply the absolute path of the video at "INPUT_FILE_NAME"  and give a random string like "test" for "STREAM_NAME".  Then once you run your program the video should be live. I see you are interested in hls streaming so I recommend this article. https://medium.com/@HoseungJang/video-streaming-with-node-js-9401213a04e7